# Examples of the unnecessary prefix "pre/prae"

Tags: classical-latin, etymology

I think that Fowler's *Modern English Usage* takes issue with the practice of needlessly inserting "pre" before words which already contain the idea, as in "pre-alerts" that patients are coming into the hospital. The Latin words "paro" and "praeparo" suggest that the problem is not a new one. Are there other Latin examples?

Comment: "Pre-alert" may be ugly, but it's perfectly logical. I can alert you to something that happened in the past, that is currently happening, or that will happen in the future. "Pre-alert" gives more precision in expressing the third of those meanings, although in some contexts there might be no ambiguity that needed to be resolved. From the wording of the question, it sounds like you're doing this from memory and don't have a copy of Fowler handy. I have the 2nd edition, and there is nothing like this in the entry for "pre-," just a comment on hyphenation.

Comment: Paro seems to have many meanings that don't include any implication of doing something beforehand. I arrange the books on my bookshelf in alphabetical order. I provide my dogs with food. I make friends with my neighbor. I adorn my apartment with posters. I assume that praeparo would be more specific. I prearrange my books in preparation for tomorrow's research. I adorn my apartment with posters so it will look good tomorrow when my old girlfriend visits.

Comment: There does seem to have been a drift, though because the Vulgate has "numquid poterit Deus parare mensam in deserto" (Ps 78:19) which the Geneva version translates "Can God prepare a table in the wilderness." Did praeparare displace parare in its meaning of "prepare"?